# create form number input and validate it

Tags: vuetify.js

How do I validate a number input field for positive integers correctly? I use these rules

```
  numberRules: [
    v => v.length > 0 || 'This field may not be empty',
    v => Number.isInteger(v) || 'The value must be an integer number',
    v => v > 0 || 'The value must be greater than zero'
  ]
```

but get wrong results. I created an example showing my wrong behaviour

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-with-vuetify-eagles-yqxcc

To modify the textfield as a number input I added `type="number"` as a component property.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get wrong result because `v` in your rules methods is actually `string` (yes yes, fun fact :) ).

You can:

1. change your rule to `v => Number.isInteger(Number(v)) || "The value must be an integer number",`
2. add `.number` modifier to `v-model=...` to looks like `v-model.number=...`. But in that case you first rule method wouldn't work, because `v` as number doesn't have `.length`

Comment: thanks for your reply. Would you mind providing a modified sandbox? I changed my second rule to `v => Number.isInteger(Number(v))` but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Can you check this https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-with-vuetify-eagles-hjf1j

Comment: And this one with `.number` modifier. https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-with-vuetify-eagles-3hdky

Comment: I tried the samples and without modifying the fields I get no valid form, when clicking on a field and leaving it, I get errors shown up like `field may not be empty` here is my code https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-with-vuetify-eagles-1jtdf

Comment: Ah, that's because initial value is `number` but after change it is `string`. Crazy JS!
Use `String(v).length > 0` in first rule.

Comment: yes that worked :) Do you know an additional rule to forbid the special characters like `4566+++` or `10,` or something like that?

Comment: Do you mean check value/validation on typing? You can use keyboard events on field, and check value on every `keydown` or `keypressed`.

Comment: sorry no :) I mean it's still possible to type something like `123++++++++` or `,,,456,,,` so I would  have to check if the string contains numeric letters only I think ...